# Compare 2 CSV files and add value from one file to another of the match item

Tags: python

I have 2 CSV files and when there is a match of name I want to add the date to CSV1 file as shown in the example below.

**Content of CSV1:**

```
Num    Name   ID
1      aaa    129
2      bbb    298
3      ccc    654
```

**Content of CSV2:**

```
Area   Size    Name    Region     Date
US     34      aaa     MW         02/12/18
US     21      ccc     WS         11/22/13
EU     76      bbb     UK         07/02/15
```

**Result of CSV1:**

```
Num    Name   ID      Date
1      aaa    129     02/12/18
2      bbb    298     07/02/15
3      ccc    654     11/22/13
```

Here is my code.

```
import csv
with open('build.csv', 'rb') as master:
master_indices = dict((r[2], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)))
with open('build.csv', 'rb') as masterdates:
master_dates = dict((r[4], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(masterdates)))
with open('bip.csv', 'rb') as hosts:
with open('results.csv', 'wb') as results:
reader = csv.reader(hosts)
writer = csv.writer(results)
writer.writerow(next(reader, []) + ['Date Rebuild'])
for row in reader:
index = master_indices.get(row[1])
if index is not None:
message = list(master_dates)[index]
else:
message = 'NOT FOUND in master list'
writer.writerow(row + [message])
```

The result dates are not correct.

```
Num    Name   ID      Date
1      aaa    129     7/2/15
2      bbb    298     2/12/18
3      ccc    654     11/22/13
```

Comment: Hello! Did you try anything before posting your question? If so, please, show your code.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas package you should be able to solve it.

```
csv1.merge(csv2, left_on='Name', right_on='Name')
```

However, I recommend you to read the [guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)